# How do you detect if an attribute like password has changed in typeorm

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

In typeorm, I am trying to use a subscriber decorator to hash users password before persisting to the database. Unfortunately, I can't find a reference in the docs.

In sequelizejs, I use the following code,

```
User.hashPassword = (user, options) => {
    if (!user.changed('password')) {
      return null;
    }
    // hash password
    return Bcrypt.hash(user.get('password'), SALT_ROUNDS)
      .then(hash => user.set('password', hash));
  };
```

Right now, I am trying to migrate the code to `typeorm` and my translation is roughly

```
@BeforeInsert()
@BeforeUpdate()
hashPassword() {
    // conditional to detect if password has changed goes here
    this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, SALT_ROUNDS);
}
```

The issue is, I stuck at `!user.changed('password')`. Is there an equivalent function in `typeorm` to do this without rolling out my own solution?

Comment: Did you find some solution for this?

Comment: @Hammerbot No, I did not. What I did was to check if the `user.password` property is present in the update request. If it is present, confirm that it is a plain string to prevent a double hash. Then manually run the `bcrypt.hash()` on the plain string before persisting.

Comment: Have you tried using a subscriber? https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/listeners-and-subscribers.md#what-is-a-subscriber

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to this question was found in @adetoola's own [issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2624).
You can use `@AfterLoad` to load the user password and check if the current password is different:

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    public username: string;

    @Column()
    public password: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    public jwtToken: string;

    private tempPassword: string;


    @AfterLoad()
    private loadTempPassword(): void {
        this.tempPassword = this.password;
    }

    @BeforeUpdate()
    private encryptPassword(): void {
        if (this.tempPassword !== this.password) {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's important to note here that Entity Listeners are not fired when using repository methods like `.update()` and `.delete()` since the entity is not loaded. If you want to make sure these methods fire, you need to load the entity (with `.findOne()`), update it and then use the `.save()` method. See [this github thread](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2036#issuecomment-385331765) for more details

Comment: But how do you validate password length etc with `class-validator` in encryptPassword? Would you do it manually instead?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
@BeforeInsert()
@BeforeUpdate()
hashPassword() {
  if (this.password) {
    this.password = createHmac('sha256', this.password).digest('hex');
  }
}
```

I just check if a password is present in the DTO (before update and insert). If it is present, I should hash it.

Answer (score 1):

```
----------

    private tempPassword: string

  /// commit to handle the password if i not change it it will be  not encription


  @AfterLoad()
  private loadTempPassword(): void {
    this.tempPassword = this.password;
  }




  @BeforeInsert()
  @BeforeUpdate()
  async hashPassword(): Promise<void> {
    // cheack if that password changing or not
    if (this.tempPassword !== this.password) {

      try {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)

      } catch (e) {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException('there are some issiue in the hash')

      }
    }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

we can make the selection of password from the Column

```
 @Column('string', { select: false })
   password:string
```

then we try to hash

```
we check if the password is found or not 
 if (this.password) {
//make hash 
}
```

or another way
it should make   private tempPassword: string

```
   @AfterLoad()
  private loadTempPassword(): void {
    this.tempPassword = this.password;
  }
```

or

```
@BeforeInsert()
  @BeforeUpdate()
  async hashPassword(): Promise<void> {
    // cheack if that password changing or not
    if (this.password) {
      if (this.tempPassword !== this.password) {

        try {
          this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 10)

        } catch (e) {
          throw new InternalServerErrorException('there are some issiue in the hash')

        }
      }
    }
```